# C# LDAP Access Violation when trying to get a list of users

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Ok, so I've made my connection to the AD server, and created users without any issues. However, when I try to get a list of users, it always fails.

I can connect using LDAP://domain.com, "user", "password" but when I try anything else, the access violation comes up. 
EX: LDAP://CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com or LDAP://domain.com/CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com returns the access violation exception. If I do a search through the root and get the path, and create a new entry with the path, I get the access violation.

It seems like I can only connect to the root. I don't know how to get a list of users from there. Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**
This is the code I ended up working with. It works the way I want it to. I'll leave it up here in case anyone ever runs into this problem. I've added comments to the code where the error popped up.

```
private void List_Logon()
        {
            DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.com", "user", "password", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(Entry);
            searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))";
            SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();
            //I had to add null checks. This was never a problem, but should be checked. 
            if (results != null)
            {
                //For some odd reason, I couldn't use a foreach here.
                for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry user = results[i].GetDirectoryEntry();
                        //This information cannot return null or it will throw an Access Violation Exception. 
                        if (user.Properties["Name"].Value != null & user.Properties["lastLogon"].Value != null)
                        {
                            //This part is not mine. Someone else told me how to convert it.
                            Int64 lastlogon = new Int64();
                            IADsLargeInteger lgInt =
                            (IADsLargeInteger)user.Properties["lastLogon"].Value;
                            lastlogon = ((long)lgInt.HighPart << 32) + lgInt.LowPart;
                            DateTime lastLogonTime = DateTime.FromFileTime(lastlogon);
                            //Thank you.
                            listBox1.Items.Add(user.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString() + " : " + lastLogonTime.ToString());
                        }
                        //If one of the above is null, I still want to try to get the user.
                        else if (user.Properties["Name"].Value != null)
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Add(user.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Don't believe this will ever happen, but it's possible... I think. I'm still learning. 
                            listBox1.Items.Add("result was null");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                         //This is how I found out what was really wrong. Catching the Access Violation Exception did not work. This was returning a Null Reference message.
                         MessageBox.Show(e.Message(), "Error");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there really no one out there that can help?

Comment: Are you sure that the user you've binding to Active Directory with has permissions to query the directory? Check this KB article on allowing these types of queries : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320528

Comment: Perhaps you could post the code and the associated exception?

Comment: I figured it out. It was null references in the fields I was trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

Access Violation Exception was incorrect. I added a try-catch to discover the problem was a Null Reference Exception.